# Allow non-technical user to change content of website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have recently developed a website for a client using the html + css + js + php stack. The client is non-technical and she would now like to be able to edit the text content of the site, change the links, change the photos, without having to bother with the code behind.

I know this is quite opinion-based, but I was wondering what good approach may I have in this case?

Things I thought of so far:

1. Integrate with WordPress, but it seems this is not possible without rewriting the entire site from scratch
2. Create an AdminPanel of my own, but this would take too much time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...without having to bother with the code behind.

The code is only one aspect.

> ...like to be able to edit the text content of the site...

Does your client know how to write for the web?  Does she know how to use data from analytics, surveys, and user testing to optimize that content?

> ...change the links...

From what to what?  When I've had clients request this in the past, they wanted the freedom to upend the navigation of the site.  If they don't really understand all the considerations that went into that navigation in the first place, they shouldn't be messing with it (in general).

> ...change the photos...

I don't know too many clients who also know how to properly crop, size, and compress their photos for web use.  Some of this can be automated, but in designs where that cropping is dynamic, such as due to responsive design, more forethought is required.

Your client probably also doesn't know how, or have the tools, to test this site across multiple browsers.  It's unlikely they know version control.

> Things I thought of so far:
>
> 1. Integrate with WordPress, but it seems this is not possible without rewriting the entire site from scratch
> 2. Create an AdminPanel of my own, but this would take too much time.

The admin panel option essentially leads you down the path of making your own CMS.  You're right to assume that this would take too much time.  If there really were some minor changes that the client wanted to make, it would be fine to do some very simple dynamic data.  This data can even come from something as simple as a Google Doc, which the client edits!  But usually you'll find that this will repeatedly get added to over time, and you'll have the worst of both words.... an unmanageable hacked together CMS, with none of the time saving, and none of the flexibility.

WordPress or some other CMS is probably an acceptable option if your client is demanding this sort of control.  The amount work you've put into the site so far is totally irrelevant to what needs to be done next.  Also, the bulk of your work can be re-used, allowing you to rapidly build out the site with a CMS.

Really though, you should ensure your client has actually considered everything that goes into the site.  Make sure they're crystal clear that once you turn over the keys, that they might as well have not hired someone to build this out in the first place.  Some clients are good about this and can make informed decisions on their own.  Most can't.  It's up to you and your client to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience since I am still a student, but I think rewriting the entire site from scratch would take more time than adding features. All you have to do is add a couple of them.

...If by AdminPanel you mean she can log in on the website as administrator and have access that regular users don't have such as `edit` and `new` buttons and stuff.

Comment: This can work, but keep in mind that the current requirements are not likely to be tomorrow's requirements.  It's best to plan ahead and consider what the needs will be a year from now.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I appreciate it. After reading your answer, I agree with you and the client might then comeback to ask for more and more and in the end it's not going to be productive for him. Might as well give something that fits her needs more and sadly if it means to start over, might as well do it and close the case.

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress is the obvious answer, but it sounds like you've already finished the work and would need to start from scratch.

I would probably just ask them what kind of content they think will be likely needed to change over time, and pull those strings from either an XML or SQL. That way, they either open PhpMyAdmin (one table with the text to be displayed in particular segments of the page) or an XML file, CTRL+F for the text that's there now, change it, done.

For images, I'd just tell them to put the new image file in the "img" directory with the same name as the old one, overwrite.

Maybe give them a one-page PDF with all the information they need to do this.